# Need to convert two dimensional array response in to json Object in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting below response from backend(NodeJS),

**current Response**:

```
 [ [ '49' ], [ '33' ], [ '60' ], [ '58' ] ]
```

Need to pass these above  values to Highchart component in JSON Object format as like below in my frontend -Angular 9. I am facing issues in converting two dimensional array values to its corresponding json format.

Here key 'fin' and its values should be static. For  key -"A" , i need array element 1,3,.. and for key -"B" i need array elements 2,4,etc .

Can anyone guide me , Please.

**Required format:**

```
{
"fin":[
       '14',
       '16'
      ]
"A" : [
       '49',
       '60'
      ]
"B" : [
       '33',
       '58'
      ]
}
```

Comment: if there is more than one element inside array at (0) position, say[['49, '2nd_ele'], [],...], should the output show "A": ['49', '2nd_ele', '60'] ?

Comment: Pleas post what you have tried and some code snippet. SO does not programming service.

Comment: @Chandra.  I will get only one array element (position 0) always inside inner array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go about it, would be to, segregate the *currentResponse* array as per need.

```
listA = [];
listB = [];
for (i = 0; i < currentResponse.length; i++) {
  if(i%2==0) listA.push(currentResponse[i][0]);
  else listB.push(currentResponse[i][0]);
}
```

Once segregated, we can build the JSON as a simple JS Object

```
jsonObj = {
  fin : [
       '14',
       '16'
      ]
  A : listA
  B : listB
}
```

Comment: Hi Chandra.. Thanks for your  answer .. Its worked !..